# magento : user file upload

Tags: php, magento

i need to allow a customer to upload a picture, or a text in a textarea, associated with that product while putting it on his cart.

I looked in configurable products attributes, but you can only make dropdown or multiple selects, no textarea or upload fields.

Is there a built-in solution for this ? Reading magento forums, i saw the user upload option was implemented in magento 1.3, but isn't available in my magento ver. (1.7.0.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom option with input type "file".

Comment: good clue, even if i'm looking for an automated solution. The final user of the shop isn't familiar with new techs. Anyway, thanks you

Comment: it allows customer to upload file at the product page. File is available in cart and in backend after order is completed. All validations are done automatically. You are looking for something else? "i need to allow a customer to upload a picture, or a text in a textarea, associated with that product while putting it on his cart."

Comment: i meant the final administrator as the final user x) sorry. It's still a good solution, i'll write a walkthrough for the backoffice anyway.

Comment: @SupFig It's not only a good solution. It's te Magento-way-of-life-solution. This is how user uploads are realized in Magento. What do you mean by "automated solution"? How could you automate an user upload without knowing hwat the user will upload?

Comment: i first imagined that, with the customizable products, i could set a file upload attribute filled by the user, but it can only be done with a dropdown or a multiselect. The custom option solution force the administrator to re-create the field for every new product. But it's still the best solution, so i'll use it.

Comment: There's still a problem apparently; I added this upload file input to let the customer link a picture to the product, but i can't get the said picture in the order, nothing's different from a classic order. Any clues ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any built-in way to do this, you can create an attribute though for it.

You can allow your customer to write comments before placing an order with this Free extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-order-comment.html

Comment: thanks for the extension, but i need a textarea on each product's page, and in general on each products, not on the order action. The shop sells engraved glass blocks, and the custom text/image is the engraved thing.
I'm new to magento, and i had the feeling that i can't create the right attribute with the attribute system. By 'creating an attribute' , you mean override attribute class ?

Comment: Then you will want to add a textarea in HTML beneath every product in cart, and add column to tables `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_order_item`, which will get updated with the value of textarea. You may need to write observer here. I'm afraid if I've scared you with this.

Comment: @SupFrig This is a totally different description like the one from your question above. Do you want to allow an upload for the customers? Or do you want to add additional media as product attribute from the backend when adding products? (what I thought first after reading you question…). Please update yuor question to make that point clear.

Comment: I think there is a column where you can save custom options of product in serialized way in `sales_flat_order_item`. No need to create column then.

Comment: @Kalpesh Mehta Never ever touch Magento database table or the hell will open right in front of you… (or at least you will feel a great pain in the ass on the next software update).

Comment: @feeela sorry for misunderstanding, it's the customer who have to upload the picture/text.

Answer (score 1):

There are some extensions available at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ but I didn't test them as they are mostly with costs. I also found a free one, but didn't test that either: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-attachments-extension.html

Comment: this extension works fine for an administrator adding a media content (video or other files that img), but i needed an upload button for the customer, so he could link a file of his choice to the product he's buying. Seems my original question isn't well asked (i'm not an english native)